# How to find the maximum and minimum value of an equation with x²and y²?

Tags: calculus

Example : Under the condition 2x² + y² = 4 for real numbers x,y ,the maximum value of 4x + y² is A and the minimum one is B

How I'm supposed to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: $4x+y^2=4x+4-2x^2$. Now maximize, minimize as usual, recalling that $-\sqrt{2}\le x\le \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: You can try the lagrange multiplier method (link). The function is $\mathcal L=4x+y^2+\lambda(4-2x^2-y^2)$ link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

Answer (score 1):

Lagrange optimization is useful when you are given a scalar function of multiple variables, $f(x,y)$, and a constraint $g(x,y)$. I think it is a good technique to know, although as André pointed out it isn't too difficult to isolate $x$ in this particular problem.

The set up is to solve first order conditions, or when the line normal to the tangent plane to your function is parallel to the line perpendicular to the tangent plane on your constraint or when there is some $\lambda$ for which
$$
\nabla f(x,y)=\lambda\nabla g(x,y)
$$
I often use this even when things aren't terrible to solve for a single variate function, as I make lots of algebra mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

**[Lagrange-Multiplier method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)**

$\mathcal L=4x+y^2+\lambda(4-2x^2-y^2)$

Differentiating w.r.t $x,y$ and $\lambda$. Then setting the derivatives equal to 0.

$\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial x}=4-\lambda\cdot 4x=0 \quad (1)$

$\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial y}=2y-\lambda\cdot 2y=0 \quad (2)$

$\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \lambda}=4-2x^2-y^2=0 \quad (3)$

Putting the terms with lambda on the RHS for $(1)$ and $(2)$.

$4=\lambda\cdot 4x$

$2y=\lambda\cdot 2y$

Dividing one equation by the other equation, assuming for the moment that $y\neq 0$

$0.5y=0.5\frac{y}{x} \Rightarrow x_{1/2}=1$

Using (3) we get $4-2-y^2=0\Rightarrow y_{1/2}=\pm\sqrt 2 $

Now we regard the case $y=0$. Using $(3)$ we get the equation

$4-2x^2-0^2=0 \Rightarrow x=\pm \sqrt 2$

Thus the critical points are$ C_1(1/\sqrt 2), C_2(1/-\sqrt 2), C_3(\sqrt 2/0)$ and $C_4(-\sqrt 2/0)$

To find out if a critical point is a (relative) maximum, (relative) minimum you can try it with the **Bordered Hessian**